# Durandal App - Not reflecting changes in view-model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, durandal

**EDIT:- I have uploaded complete code for project at [github](https://github.com/amantur/DurandalTest.git).**

Following is my view-model:

```
define(["ko",
        "service/dataService",
    'service/logger',
        'durandal/system'],
function (ko, svc, logger, system) {
    var that = this,
    results = ko.observableArray(),
    query = ko.observable();

    var SearchProduct = {
        activate: activate,
        title: 'Search',
        search: search,
        results: results,
        query: query
    };

    return SearchProduct;

    function activate() {}

    function search() {
        svc.searchProduct(query()).then(function (data) {
            results([]);results(data);
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            var msg = 'Error searching item: ' + textStatus;
            logger.logError(msg, jqXHR, system.getModuleId(svc), true);
        });;
    }
});
```

1. First thing is that in `search` function, when I call `query()`, it returns undefined.
2. Second when I search and add new items to `results` with following line:

   results(data);//data is array of 10 items

the changes are not reflected in following html template:

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-right" role="search" data-bind="submit: search">
    <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" 
                    data-bind='text: query, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"'>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>&nbsp;Search
    </button>
</form>

<section data-bind="foreach: results">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 pull-left">
            <label data-bind="text: name"></label><br/>
            <label data-bind="text:category"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 pull-right">
            <label data-bind="text:shortDescription"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

the `section` is bound using `foreach: results`. When after the change is applied (list of items added to observable) and I come to page after navigating from some other page, the following line correctly reflects the count:

```
<span data-bind="text: results().length"></span>&nbsp;items found
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:-** ***One part of puzzle is resolved***

If I use `results()` instead of `results`, the binding with list works!!!

```
<section data-bind="foreach: results()">
```

**EDIT 3:-** **Created simple `cshtml` view and used viewmodel there with `ko.applyBindings` method. It works this way. Seems I am missing some piece of `drundal` wiring**

Comment: Are you sure that the results being returned from the server contain the properties that are listed in your view?

Comment: @PWKad yes the properties are there. But can't figure out what is wrong. :( Leave alone the properties, even `results().length` is not coming until I reload the view by navigating to it again.

Comment: Can you try monitor the value of your query object? Try putting this in your view

<span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(query)"></span>

Comment: @eggward have you tried running the sample from github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems with your current code:

- Durandal 2.0.0 is using now Knockout through requrejs. (The documentation is yet everywhere updated. See the [samples](http://durandaljs.com/version/latest/HTML%20Samples.zip) as a reference) so there is no need to explicitly reference Knockout  because it can lead to strange errors like yours. And Durandal uses ko with the name `knockoutout`.
  So change your `main.js`:

  ```
  requirejs.config({
      paths: {
       //...      
       'knockout': "../Scripts/knockout-2.3.0",  
  });
  ```

  And remove the line: `define('knockout', [], function () { return ko; });`
- your `this` handling contains some errors in your viewmodel so you have created properties on the global window object instead of declaring them as private fields. So instead of `that` you need to use `var`:

  ```
  var results = ko.observableArray([]);
  var query = ko.observable('');
  ```

  And in your search method you can just reference them without any "prefix":

  ```
  return dataService.searchProduct(query()).then(function (data) {
     results([]);
     results(data);
  })
  ```

I have sent you a [pull request](https://github.com/amantur/DurandalTest/pull/1).

Comment: Well, I will try with `knockout`. The `var` and without `prefix` was already tried, but may work with changes to `ko`. If you see `myProducts.js` it is using the same things.

Comment: Yeah if you check out my pull request: https://github.com/nemesv/DurandalTest/commit/600b85cd05b440bcb789fd60c4b62ff03152213a I've also fixed the myProducts.js because it used the global ko object instead of the require js provided one.

Comment: Had another issue with `underscore`. It needs to be defined like `jQuery`. All is well and working fine now. But I still has some doubt as why the first page was working with reference to `knockoutjs` but subsequent pages stopped working. Why was it so?

Comment: Your first view `myProducts.js` worked because you have directly used the global `ko` object. While in your `searchProduct.js` you have tried use the requriejs provided knockout which caused the problems. Because you had two ko versions loaded at that point...

Answer (score 0):

Your variable declaration section has invalid syntax. Change it to:

```
var that = this, // coma needed
results = ko.observableArray(), // coma needed
query = ko.observable();
```

If you don't use the var keyword for an undefined variable it becomes a global and in strict mode that would be an error.

Hopefully that should solve your problem.

Comment: well it was with `var` before both, I tried it this way but no luck.